# Best way to rotate Rails log files daily in 2015

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging, logrotate, log-rotation

What is the best way to rotate Ruby on Rails log files daily?

I saw posts in the past. They recommended using `logrotate` and enable `copytruncate` option to avoid restarting Rails.

However, logs are lost at small time slice between copying the file and truncating it.

My project requirement does not lose logs, so we chose `cronolog` with ruby's stdlib `Logger`.
The code like the following:

```
config.logger = Logger.new(IO.popen("/usr/sbin/cronolog #{config.paths['log'].first}.%Y%m%d", "w"))
```

It's mostly works correctly, but logs are mixed when logging data size more than `PIPE_BUF` that because using PIPE.

So what is recommended way to rotate logs in such situation?

Comment: Could you explain the `PIPE_BUF` issue more? How does the issue manifest itself?

Comment: I think I understand it now, you're talking about atomic writes when there are concurrent writers. When using a pipe, and the log message is too large, the OS cannot guarantee atomic writes. Are you the author of the chrono_logger gem? Does it resolve the issue?

Comment: Yes atomic means writing logs by concurrent writers. I'm the author of chrono_logger gem. It does not necessarily solve the issue by using chrono_logger. Because chrono_logger entrust atomic logging to a file system. Some file systems takes lock when writing any size of data. For example using with CentOS's ext4 file system, chrono_logger writes logs atomically.